# What happens with "pure" Python + Cython packages during installation built failure?

Tags: pip, cython, setuptools

I just read the [Cython Pure Python Mode documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/pure.html) and I'm not sure if I understand it right. It sounds as if I could keep all my Python files as they are, add `*.pxd` files where I declare Cython types. In the setup.py, I still add

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(
        "A.py",
        compiler_directives={'language_level' : "3"}
      )
)
```

When I run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` it actually builds the .so file.

What happens when I create the sdist / bdist, upload them to PyPI and a user does not have a matching platform? They will download the sdist, sure. I guess pip / setuptools will automatically try to compile the extension modules (A.py) and I guess if that works, it is fine. But what if cythonize fails? Will it still install the package and use the pure Python code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. I believe a failure in `setup.py` aborts installation completely.

You can try to [declare an extension optional](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.Extension) but there're [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59522262/7976758) that doesn't really work. Could be an issue with older `setuptools`.

Comment: Hm ... then, I guess, one could use environment variables to add / not add the extension. For the source distribution, it would not be added and thus not built. For the wheel, I can control the environment variable and thus built it. After creating the wheel, it doesn't matter if the setup-option is set, because the .so is already in the wheel. That could work, right?

Comment: Yes, looks feasible.